# Bases of Subgroups of Infinitely Generated Free Abelian Groups

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-abelian-group

In the case when $F$ is a free abelian group of finite rank, it is known that for every subgroup $B$ of $F$ there are bases $\{b_1,\ldots,b_k\}$ and $\{f_1,\ldots,f_n\}$ of $B$ and $F,$ respectively such that $b_i=m_i f_i$ for all $i=1,\ldots,k.$ I can't find a similar result on the *infinitely generated* free abelian groups. Does it mean it is not true? If not true, are there any results on "partial proportionality"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the analogous result for infinitely generated free abelian groups were true, then it would follow that, whenever $F$ is a free abelian group and $B$ a subgroup (automatically also free), the quotient is a direct sum of cyclic groups $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z/m$. Specifically, if $F$ has a free basis $\{f_i:i\in N\}$ and $B$ has a free basis $\{b_j:j\in K\}$, where $K\subseteq N$ and, for each $j\in K$, $b_j=m_jf_j$, then $F/B$ would be the direct sum of groups $\mathbb Z/m_j$ (generated by the coset of $f_j$) for $j\in K$ and groups $\mathbb Z$ (generated by the coset of $f_i$) for all $i\in N-K$.

But every abelian group is a quotient of a free abelian group, and not every abelian group is a direct sum of cyclic groups. Probably the most familiar example is the additive group $\mathbb Q$ of rational numbers.

So, if you choose some free abelian group $F$ that maps onto the rationals, say with generators $\{f_i:i\in\mathbb N-\{0\}\}$ and the homomorphism sending $f_i$ to $1/i\in\mathbb Q$, then the kernel $B$ of this homomorphism is free but not of the form you wanted.

Comment: Beautiful answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Professor Blass. I am very curious about the "partial proporitionality", though. For instance, in your example there seem to be a basis subgroup $B$ contains a "half" of a basis of $F,$ namely
$\{ k f_k -(k+1) f_{k+1} : k \in \mathbb N \setminus \{0\} \}.$
Can this be the case in general?

Comment: @PGH I don't think you'll get any "partial proportionality" unless you define that phrase in a way that makes it trivial, like "each $b$ is a finite linear combination of $f$'s" which just repeats the fact that the $f$'s generate the ambient group. The reason I don't expect anything useful along these lines is that infinitely generated abelian groups (even countable ones) can be very complicated. The example $\mathbb Q$ that I used in my answer was chosen to be familiar, not to be typical.

Comment: Yes, the matter seems to be very much nontrivial. Thanks again, Professor Blass.